# How to Style Similar to an Exam Questi-n

Tags: css

I'm trying to style something to appear like a question on an exam, similar to this:

> 1. This is content that will wrap to the new line and will respect the left most div to make it appear like a question you would see on an exam.

Assuming an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="question-label">1. </div>
  <div class="question-text">
    How satisfied are you with life?
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried setting both `.question-label` and `question-text` to `display: block; float: left;` but this breaks the question text and number into different lines. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uhexev/2/edit)

If I remove the `float: left;` on  `.question-text` it would appear to somewhat work, however it doesn't respect the space under `.question-number`. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uhexev/3/edit)

I know CSS questions are hard to correctly answer without seeing the final product, but how would you suggest achieving this without resorting to tables?

Comment: This looks like a good work for a table, even if you consider them evil. Especially, if you have more questions under each other.

Comment: why can't you use `ol`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K6Wge/   I'd use an OL

Comment: `<ol>` tags are good and all, but I have content between each of the questions.  Not to mention how the HTML structure would turn out after that.

Comment: You can put all your content inside `li`. Its not a bad practice, I've seem many websites do that. And `li` is `block` (I think it is but not 100% sure) element so putting a `block`/`inline-block`/`inline` element inside it won't cause any validation error.

Comment: Just because I can doesn't mean I will.  If I'm going to cheat and use HTML for styling, I'd just use tables.

Comment: That's splitting hairs when you're using `DIV`s to create what is semantically an `OL`, and settled on a solution that isn't necessarily 100% supported. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @AndrewClody And after restructuring a bit of my page to use `ol`s, [this is what I found](http://jsfiddle.net/mRgc6/).  The idea is fine, but I need the content under each question to line up below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. This is my favorite:

```
.question-label, .question-text {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxzzu/

Comment: The easiest way.  Looking at support, it's not great, but IE 8+ is good enough for this project.  Also made it pretty easy to drop in and have work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your css:

```
body {
  width: 400px;
}

.num {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;

  /* this makes the "1." bound to the top. You can also use middle or bottom,
     see http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align */
  vertical-align: top;
}

.txt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}
```

The trick is `display: inline-block;`

See it also here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBLQT/)

But why don't/can't you use `<ol>` ([w3c description](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/ol)) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to indent a whole block text.

You can try just block margin with float:

[code example](http://jsbin.com/umurem/2/edit)